# Problem running oracle script from command line using sqlplus

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I'm having a problem trying to run my sql script into oracle using sqlplus. The script just populates some dummy data:

```
DECLARE 
  role1Id NUMBER;
  user1Id NUMBER;
  role2Id NUMBER;
  user2Id NUMBER;
  role3Id NUMBER;
  user3Id NUMBER;
  perm1Id NUMBER;
  perm2Id NUMBER;
  perm3Id NUMBER;
  perm4Id NUMBER;
  perm5Id NUMBER;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO PB_USER(USER_ID,USER_NAME, USER_EMAIL, USER_ACTIVEYN)
  VALUES(PB_USER_ID_SEQ.nextval, 'RoleDataManagerTests_Username', 'test@test.com',' ');

  INSERT INTO ROLES(ROLE_ID, ROLE_NAME)
  VALUES(PB_ROLE_ID_SEQ.nextval, 'Test role 1');
  INSERT INTO ROLES(ROLE_ID, ROLE_NAME)
  VALUES(PB_ROLE_ID_SEQ.nextval, 'Test role 2');
  INSERT INTO ROLES(ROLE_ID, ROLE_NAME)
  VALUES(PB_ROLE_ID_SEQ.nextval, 'Test role 3');

  SELECT ROLE_ID INTO role1Id FROM ROLES WHERE ROLE_NAME = 'Test role 1';
  SELECT USER_ID INTO user1Id FROM PB_USER WHERE USER_NAME = 'RoleDataManagerTests_Username';
  INSERT INTO USERS_ROLES(USER_ID, ROLE_ID) VALUES(user1Id, role1Id);

  SELECT ROLE_ID INTO role2Id FROM ROLES WHERE ROLE_NAME = 'Test role 2';
  SELECT USER_ID INTO user2Id FROM PB_USER WHERE USER_NAME = 'RoleDataManagerTests_Username';
  INSERT INTO USERS_ROLES(USER_ID, ROLE_ID) VALUES(user2Id, role2Id);

  SELECT ROLE_ID INTO role3Id FROM ROLES WHERE ROLE_NAME = 'Test role 3';
  SELECT USER_ID INTO user3Id FROM PB_USER WHERE USER_NAME = 'RoleDataManagerTests_Username';
  INSERT INTO USERS_ROLES(USER_ID, ROLE_ID) VALUES(user3Id, role3Id);

  INSERT INTO PERMISSIONS(PERMISSION_ID, KEY, DESCRIPTION)
  VALUES (PB_PERMISSION_ID_SEQ.nextval, 'perm1', 'permission 1');
  INSERT INTO PERMISSIONS(PERMISSION_ID, KEY, DESCRIPTION)
  VALUES (PB_PERMISSION_ID_SEQ.nextval, 'perm2', 'permission 2');
  INSERT INTO PERMISSIONS(PERMISSION_ID, KEY, DESCRIPTION)
  VALUES (PB_PERMISSION_ID_SEQ.nextval, 'perm3', 'permission 3');
  INSERT INTO PERMISSIONS(PERMISSION_ID, KEY, DESCRIPTION)
  VALUES (PB_PERMISSION_ID_SEQ.nextval, 'perm4', 'permission 4');
  INSERT INTO PERMISSIONS(PERMISSION_ID, KEY, DESCRIPTION)
  VALUES (PB_PERMISSION_ID_SEQ.nextval, 'perm5', 'permission 5');

  SELECT PERMISSION_ID INTO perm1Id FROM PERMISSIONS WHERE KEY = 'perm1';
  SELECT PERMISSION_ID INTO perm2Id FROM PERMISSIONS WHERE KEY = 'perm2';
  SELECT PERMISSION_ID INTO perm3Id FROM PERMISSIONS WHERE KEY = 'perm3';
  SELECT PERMISSION_ID INTO perm4Id FROM PERMISSIONS WHERE KEY = 'perm4';
  SELECT PERMISSION_ID INTO perm5Id FROM PERMISSIONS WHERE KEY = 'perm5';

  INSERT INTO ROLES_PERMISSIONS(ROLE_ID, PERMISSION_ID)
  VALUES(role1Id, perm1Id);
  INSERT INTO ROLES_PERMISSIONS(ROLE_ID, PERMISSION_ID)
  VALUES(role1Id, perm2Id);
  INSERT INTO ROLES_PERMISSIONS(ROLE_ID, PERMISSION_ID)
  VALUES(role1Id, perm3Id);

  INSERT INTO ROLES_PERMISSIONS(ROLE_ID, PERMISSION_ID)
  VALUES(role2Id, perm3Id);

  INSERT INTO ROLES_PERMISSIONS(ROLE_ID, PERMISSION_ID)
  VALUES(role3Id, perm4Id);
  INSERT INTO ROLES_PERMISSIONS(ROLE_ID, PERMISSION_ID)
  VALUES(role3Id, perm5Id);
END;
/
```

My script works fine when I run it using Oracle SQL Developer but when I use the sqlplus command line tool this is what's outputted and then it just hangs:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.1.0.7.0 - Production on Tue May 11 09:49:34 2010

Copyright (c) 1982, 2008, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Oracle Label Security, OLAP, Data Mining Scoring Engine
and Real Application Testing options
```

I'm running the tool using this command line, which works fine for other scripts:

```
sqlplus username/password@server/dbname @Setup.sql
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: what happens when you connect to your db via sqlplus, and then at the prompt call the script?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to either put an `exit` at the end of the script, or run it as `sqlplus username/password@server/dbname < Setup.sql` (i.e. redirected input, `<` instead of `@`). You can check if that's the issue by just typing 'exit' in the hanging session.

If it is really hanging, have you committed or rolled back the execution from Developer?

Comment: even without the `exit`, it should do *something*, ie complete and display a prompt.

Comment: true, I'm usually running with `-s` when I make this mistake

Comment: Yeah sorry my fault, it's the transaction which isn't commited. First time I've used oracle or any of these tools!

Comment: for me this just seems to dump loads of numbers to the screen.  Any idea what that's about?!  They basically increment up to the line number but it writes them out in a matrix

Comment: @JonnyLeeds - if you don't have `-s` onthe command line, you see the script line numbers. You'll be left at a numbered prompt; if hitting return generates a new number, you're writing a PL/SQL block, otherwise you'll get an `sql>` prompt. Either way you haven't told it to execute. You need a `/` on its own on the line after the block's final `end`.

Comment: thanks that's useful to know.  At that point I was getting different behaviour running manually from the command line and a scripted command line run

Answer (score 15):

I was seeing this problem as well with certain scripts that would execute fine in a client like TOAD, but when being executed via SQLPlus with the @script directive instead of hanging, the SQLPlus client would return a prompt with a number on it which corresponded to the number of lines in the script being executed (+1).

For example, if we executed a script named 'doit.sql' that had 70 lines we would start SQLPlus with the appropriate command and enter:

`> @doit.sql`

Then we would see:

`71:`

Pressing enter at this point would return

`72:`

We were able to get these scripts executed by entering `/` at the prompt and pressing enter.

Comment: I had similar, hanging with just a number I could increment by pressing enter. I redirected my script into my SQLPlus command, using `<` instead of `@` and the script ended and returned to the command prompt, as per the suggestion in [@alex-poole's post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2809504/304330), above. Unfortunately, I couldn't just add `EXIT`, as my import led to a number of 3rd party scripts, shared around the business in our code repository.

Answer (score 8):

The Simple answer

Make sure you put both 'end;' and in final line put '/'

It will run with ease.

Comment: fixed it for me.

Comment: @Yoav24 also for me.  Oracle is... beyond aggravating.

Answer (score 1):

The command line

```
sqlplus username/password@server/dbname @Setup.sql
```

mentioned above means that `sqlplus` should execute the script `Setup.sql` and wait further commands interactively (if script does not do `exit` explicitly). This is a normal behavior of `sqlplus`.

`sqlplus` terminates in three cases:

- Failure (for some errors you can change if it terminates or not. See `WHENEVER` plsql-command)
- Explicit `exit` (both interactive and sript)
- End of STDIN (EOF)

Either from interactive mode or from script you can send `^Z` character to softly terminate input flow. Interactively you just press `Ctrl+Z,Enter`.

And, of course, you may redirect STDIN, and take it from file, not from keyboard. There are two similar ways to do this:

```
1) sqlplus username/password@server/dbname<Setup.sql
2) echo @Setup.sql|sqlplus username/password@server/dbname
```

In both cases `sqlplus` will terminate after the script execution because of `EOF` in the input flow.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `/` at the prompt, ensure that your query in the doit.sql ends with a semicolon.

Comment: This should have been a comment to cwash's answer, but is wrong anyway; getting the line number prompts indicates it was a PL/SQL block, which would require the `/` (as well as the `;`, which must already be there or it still wouldn't work).

Answer (score 0):

Issue is because of SQLplus was running from the oracle client home and it was crashing on running the startup upgrade command.

Run the sqlplus from the non-client oracle home and tried the commands then it works as expected.
so resolution is to run the sqlplus from the main oracle home instead of oracle client home.