# sqplus command after sqload

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using SQLOAD to import some data into a table, afterwards I want to
do some stuff with the data with sqlplus.

I am doing all of it with a batch-fiel:

```
@echo off
for %%i in ("C:\Users\testDirectory\*.csv") do (
    > "controlfile.ctl" (
        echo load data
        echo INFILE 'controlfile.ctl'
        echo into table TABLE_NAME
        echo append
        echo fields terminated by ','
        echo OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' AND '"'
        echo trailing nullcols
        echo            ^(
        echo                 COLUMN1 CHAR^(4000^),
        echo                 COLUMN2 CHAR^(4000^),
                             .......
        echo            ^)
    )
    sqlldr db_user/db_pw CONTROL='C:\testDirectory\controlfile.ctl' LOG='C:\Users\testDirectory\logf.log' skip=1
)

sqlplus db_user/db_pw @sqlprocedure.sql
EXIT
```

If I run the batch-file then all rows will be imported, however if I execute my sql-script afterwards then it hangs. The transcation stays open and won't close...

However, If the sqlldr is not executed then my script-file gets executed successfully..

My sqlscript contains a very large procedure which work correctly on the database. It looks like this:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DEFINE dynamic_filename = idle
COLUMN which_dynamic NEW_VALUE dynamic_filename

SELECT  TO_CHAR( SYSDATE, 'YYYYMMDD' )
       ||'_'
       ||TO_CHAR( SYSDATE, 'HH24MISS' )
       ||'.log'   which_dynamic
  FROM dual;

SET TERMOUT ON

SPOOL log\&dynamic_filename   

BEGIN

 ...my code...
END;
/
EXIT
spool off
```

Comment: Well, what is in `sqlprocedure.sql`? I imagine it doesn't have its own `exit` command at the end, so SQL`*Plus doesn't know it's finished?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2809267/266304)?

Comment: I edited my question with more information. I actually tried the solution on that link, before I posted my question here

Answer (score 0):

You script works fine if I replace `...my code...` with `null;`. I recommend you grant `alter session` to the user running this script and then put this in your script just before the `BEGIN`:

```
select value from v$diag_info where name = 'Default Trace File';
alter session set events '10046 trace name context forever, level 8';
```

Then watch the trace file. There are *lots* of goodies in the trace file.

Comment: I do not understand how to read these trace-files...cannot find them in my directory

Comment: The problem must be somehow connected with the sqlldr command, because the sqplus command works if the sqlldr is not executed....Only the combination together doesnt work

Comment: I am not sure if I was clear enough...my sqlscript works...it just doesnt work when in combination with the sqloader ...If i execute the sqlldr command then afterwards the my scrip with sqplus then it hangs...

Comment: You were clear. If you don't put any data in your tables, then the SQL statements probably finish quickly. As soon as you put data in the tables, the SQL statements take a *very* long time to finish (if ever). If you want to know what is going on behind the scene, you can know everything if you trace it. If you have no access to the trace file, then you might appeal to your DBA regarding the trace data or you can appeal to the DBA regarding access to v$session, v$sql, and so forth.